# Get input type to show "open in new tab" on right click

Tags: javascript, php, html, input, hyperlink

Is there a way to get input type to show "open in new tab" on right click, like how a link would do? Thanks.

```
<a href = 'www.test.com'> www.test.com </a>
<input type = 'submit' value = 'click'>
```

Comment: You could also style a link to look like a button (and maybe submit over JavaScript)

Comment: The context menu entry for opening in new tab is a browser thing that is displayed on hyperlinks. An input type is a formfield and doesn't count as link resource. You can make a custom context menu (needs some css/javascript to make it work) that appears instead of the default one.